# Print page with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

Does anybody of you know how it's possible to print a section of my website using Angular 5? I tried finding a solution on the internet, but it seems to me that there are only solutions available for Angular.

Comment: i think you can only print full page and not only one section, code to run is `window.print()`

Comment: You can try to hide stuff you don't want to print using css: `@media print {...}`

Comment: there's the problem with `window.print()` , it does not print the whole page if it's bigger than the screen a.k.a scrollable. Is there any chance to bypass that issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is 2 ways you can do it. 
1. using print-js

```
npm install print-js
```

add the script route to the angular-cli.json

```
"../node_modules/print.js/src/index.js"
```

add the print functionality to the html file

```
<div class="welcome-screen-wrapper-new-test">
  <div class="welcome-screen-header" id="what-needs-to-be-printed-page">
```

***printing section goes here***

```
 </div>
  <div class="new-test-print">
```

***onClick function goes here***

```
 <div class="print-wrapper" onclick="printJS('print-page', 'html')">
      <span class="icon print"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

DONE!

2. Insert this script tag

`<script src="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.js"></script>`

Add use the same html format.

GOODLUCK!

Answer (score 0):

I use another way
in tsconfig.json in the compilerOptions add this property allowSyntheticDefaultImports : true, then import printjs inside of my component like that :
import print from 'print-js/src/index'
finally, used it